# Create a float from two int numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I construct a float value from two whole values?

```
var amountBeforeComma = 5;
var amountAfterComma = 234;

var amount = ?? //amount == 5.234
```

Comment: `parseFloat(amountBeforeComma + '.' + amountAfterComma)` or `ammountBeforeComma + amountAfterComma / 1000`

Comment: I guess you mean parseFloat ?

Comment: @naortor Yeah, got confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one mentioned... There's the JavaScript way:

```
var num = +(amountBeforeComma + "." + amountAfterComma);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's the math way, using [logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm):

```js
var amountBeforeComma = 5;
var amountAfterComma = 234;
var amount = amountBeforeComma +
    amountAfterComma * Math.pow(10, -(Math.floor(Math.log10(amountAfterComma)) + 1));
console.log(amount);
```

`Math.log10(amountAfterComma)` gives us the *common logarithm* of `amountAfterComma`, then `Math.floor(...)` on that gives us the *characteristic* of it (`2` in your example), which is (as the linked Wikipedia page puts it) *"how many places the decimal point must be moved so that it is just to the right of the first significant digit"*. Then we add one to that and make it a negative (e.g., -3 in your example) and raise raise 10 to that power to get a value to multiply it by (`0.001` in your example) to put it where it should go. Add the `amountBeforeComma` and we're done.

Or the string then parse way:

```js
var amountBeforeComma = 5;
var amountAfterComma = 234;
var amount = parseFloat(amountBeforeComma + "." + amountAfterComma);
console.log(amount);
```

(Or use `+(amountBeforeComma + "." + amountAfterComma)` to convert with implicit coercion rather than explicit parsing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by casting numbers to strings and then parsing it as float.

```
var amount = parseFloat(amountBeforeComma + '.' + amountAfterComma);
```